# Compare List<T> and Datatable values and update list using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have List as input to a method and compare that with datatable values and update the same list based on values in datatable. For Example,

```
class Account
{
   string accountno{ get; set;}
   string status {get; set;} 
   string bankName {get; set;}
}
```

`List<Account> will have`

```
{"ABC123", "", "HDFC"}
{"ABC345", "", "BOA"}
{"ABC111", "", "BOA"}
{"ABC222", "", "RBS"}
{"ABC333", "", "RBS"}
{"ABC789", "ACTIVE", "RBS"}
```

Datatable will have values like,

```
AccountNo  Status 
ABC123     ACTIVE
ABC345     INACTIVE
ABC456     ACTIVE
ABC789     INACTIVE
```

I want to write LINQ query and update Status in List comparing AccountNo. from Datatable.

Sometime datatable could have 0 records also.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in Datatable)
{
   Account acc = list.Find(a=>a.accountno == dr.ItemArray["AccountNo"])
   acc.Status = //assign value here
}
```

This is a crude approach, and I am not an expert in LINQ.

Please help me to write the query.

Comment: What have you tried already? Where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: you would access the `Status` in the `DataRow dr` the same way as you already have accessed the account number: `dr.ItemArray["AccountNo"]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps. We join the collections on the `accountno` and than we iterate the matching items setting the account status to the matching datarow status value.

```
var q = from account in accounts
        join row in dt.AsEnumerable() on account.accountno equals row.Field<string>("AccountNo")
        select new { account, status = row.Field<string>("Status")};
            
    foreach (var match in q)
        match.account.status = match.status;
```

Joining will be much more efficient than using list.Find